Argo CD Deployment with Helmfile Plugin - VolumeMounts Not Found
I'm trying to set up an Argo CD deployment with a Helmfile plugin in my Rancher kubernetes cluster, following this reference document. However, I am encountering issues with volume mounts not being found. Here are the details of my setup:
ConfigMap.yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cmp-helmfile
  namespace: argocd
data:
  plugin.yaml: |
    apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
    kind: ConfigManagementPlugin
    metadata:
      name: cmp-helmfile
    spec:
      version: v1.0
      init:
        command: [sh, -c, 'echo "Initializing..."']
      generate:
        command: [sh, -c]
        args: ["helmfile template --quiet --namespace $ARGOCD_APP_NAMESPACE"]
      discover:
        fileName: "helmfile.yaml"


kubectl apply -f cmp-helmfile.yaml -n argocd

Deployment.yaml:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: argocd-repo-server
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: cmp-helmfile
          securityContext:
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsUser: 999
          image: ghcr.io/helmfile/helmfile:v0.157.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          # Entrypoint should be Argo CD lightweight CMP server i.e. argocd-cmp-server
          command: [/var/run/argocd/argocd-cmp-server]
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/run/argocd
              name: var-files
            - mountPath: /home/argocd/cmp-server/plugins
              name: plugins
            - mountPath: /home/argocd/cmp-server/config/plugin.yaml
              subPath: plugin.yaml
              name: cmp-helmfile
            - mountPath: /tmp
              name: cmp-tmp
      volumes:
        - name: cmp-helmfile
          configMap:
            name: cmp-helmfile
        - emptyDir: {}
          name: cmp-tmp



kubectl -n argocd patch deployments/argocd-repo-server --patch-file
.\argocd-repo-server-patch.yaml

Error Message:
spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[0].name: Not found: "var-files"
spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts1.name: Not found: "plugins"

I am unsure about the source for /var/run/argocd. According to the reference document, it seems like it should be provided by Argo CD, but I can't find details on how it is supposed to be mounted.
Questions:
Where should the /var/run/argocd mount come from, and how should it be defined in the deployment?
How can I resolve the error indicating that var-files and plugins volumes are not found?
Any guidance on these issues would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
